# Is it possible the PC can connect these two microcontrollers' serial ports?

Tags: serialport

As shown in the drawing below, MCU1 is connected to the PC via port COM7 and MCU2 is connected to the PC via port COM6:

[image]

Is it possible that MCU1 and MCU2 can communicate without writing a special computer code myself? I know for virtual ports there was a tool called comcom but in this case both ports are physical. I want PC to act as a bridge such that as if MCU1 and MCU2 are connected via their serial interface so they can send data to each other.

Comment: why don't you eliminate the PC?

Comment: Because I can only remote connect long story. I cannot access physically.

Comment: By "remote connect" you mean your PC is accessing the PC between the MCUs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029255/how-do-i-bridge-two-physical-serial-ports-to-each-other-in-software-and-log-the Seems to offer a few solutions is the software recommendation and programmatic departments.

Comment: the hub4com inside the com0com project might work ... also try the tcp2com program

Comment: com0com doesnt work. it works only for virtual ports

Comment: hub4com doesnt work in windows 10 and 11.  tcp2com looks its not free .

Comment: i downloaded tcp2com  for trial use and its a shitty program. no explanation how to bridge ports. it asks for a port and then  nothing happens. lots of tcp garbage, it definitely does not work for my purpose.